# Redis bug when creating separate Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

**ABP Framework version:** v3.3
**User Interface:** Angular

- Exception message and **stack trace**:
  2020-11-10 17:08:34.362 +02:00 [INF] Hosting environment: Development
  2020-11-10 17:08:34.362 +02:00 [INF] Content root path: C:\abp\test\aspnet-core\src\Test.IdentityServer
  2020-11-10 17:08:34.630 +02:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44372/
  2020-11-10 17:08:34.955 +02:00 [WRN] Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration')
  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration')
  at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.PrepareConfig(Object configuration) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 850
  at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.CreateMultiplexer(Object configuration, TextWriter log, EventHandler`1& connectHandler) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 868 at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImplAsync(Object configuration, TextWriter log) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 818 at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.GetAndRefreshAsync(String key, Boolean getData, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.GetAsync(String key, CancellationToken token) at Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache`2.GetAsync(TCacheKey key, Nullable`1 hideErrors, Boolean considerUow, CancellationToken token) 2020-11-10 17:08:37.259 +02:00 [WRN] Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration') System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration') at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.PrepareConfig(Object configuration) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 850 at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.CreateMultiplexer(Object configuration, TextWriter log, EventHandler`1& connectHandler) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 868
  at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImplAsync(Object configuration, TextWriter log) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 818
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token)
  at Volo.Abp.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.AbpRedisCache.SetManyAsync(IEnumerable`1 items, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token) at Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache`2.<>c__DisplayClass52_0.<g__SetRealCache|0>d.MoveNext()
  2020-11-10 17:08:37.273 +02:00 [WRN] Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration')
  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration')
  at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.PrepareConfig(Object configuration) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 850
  at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.CreateMultiplexer(Object configuration, TextWriter log, EventHandler`1& connectHandler) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 868 at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImplAsync(Object configuration, TextWriter log) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 818 at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.GetAndRefreshAsync(String key, Boolean getData, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.GetAsync(String key, CancellationToken token) at Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache`2.GetAsync(TCacheKey key, Nullable`1 hideErrors, Boolean considerUow, CancellationToken token) 2020-11-10 17:08:37.329 +02:00 [WRN] Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration') System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration') at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.PrepareConfig(Object configuration) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 850 at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.CreateMultiplexer(Object configuration, TextWriter log, EventHandler`1& connectHandler) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 868
  at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImplAsync(Object configuration, TextWriter log) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 818
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token)
  at Volo.Abp.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.AbpRedisCache.SetManyAsync(IEnumerable`1 items, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token) at Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache`2.<>c__DisplayClass52_0.<g__SetRealCache|0>d.MoveNext()

**Steps needed to **reproduce** the problem**.

1. Create new abp app via CLI or Website (https://abp.io/get-started) - angular | ef core | separate identity server
2. Specify the option to create a "Separate Identity Server"
3. Open the solution file in VS and run the API.Host & Identity Server projects
4. Check the Log files for both the API and Identity Server (see above stack trace for details)

Answer (score 2):

**To fix this problem**

I had to remove the "Redis" appsettings.json config section in both the API.Host and the Identity Server Project:
"Redis": {
"Configuration": "127.0.0.1"
},

Once I removed that the solution then worked fine.

**Closing:**
Thanks once again for an AMAZING framework ;)